# AngularJS directive fails to render replaced DOM

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm trying to make a simple directive that replaces a span with another span binding to 2 attributes of the scope:

```
.directive('exCategory', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: {
            category: '=exCategory'
        },
        replace: true,
        template: '<span class="category-label" ng-bind="category.name" style="background-color: {{category.color}};"></span>',
        link: function (scope, element) {
            console.log(scope, element);

        }
    };
})
```

This is my html:

`<span ex-category="transaction.category"></span>`

When rendered, it does nit give the color, and raises the following error on the console:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
    at $interpolate (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.1.4/angular.js:5318:24)
    at attrInterpolateLinkFn (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.1.4/angular.js:4987:27)
    at nodeLinkFn (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.1.4/angular.js:4774:13)
    at compositeLinkFn (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.1.4/angular.js:4365:15)
    at compositeLinkFn (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.1.4/angular.js:4368:13)
    at compositeLinkFn (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.1.4/angular.js:4368:13)
    at publicLinkFn (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.1.4/angular.js:4270:30)
    at ngRepeatAction (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.1.4/angular.js:14945:15)
    at Object.$watchCollectionAction [as fn] (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.1.4/angular.js:8476:11)
    at Object.Scope.$digest (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.1.4/angular.js:8570:27) <span class="category-label" style="background-color: {{category.color}};;background-color: {{category.color}};" ex-category="transaction.category">
```

Something seems wrong with the generated DOM:

`<span class="category-label" style="background-color: {{category.color}};;background-color: {{category.color}};" ex-category="transaction.category">`

If I remove the `color` bit, it works.

Any suggestions?

Edit: If I use the hit I want to render directly on my template, it works.

Edit: the problem seems to be related with the `style` tag:

`template: '<span class="category-label" ng-bind="category.name" style="aaa">{{category.color}}</span>'`

renders:

`<span class="category-label ng-binding" ng-bind="category.name" style="aaa;aaa" ex-category="transaction.category">asdads</span>`

The problem does not happen with version 1.0.1. 
JSFiddle with the problem occurring on 1.1.5:

http://jsfiddle.net/marcio0/a5KLT/

Comment: could you please share fiddle

Comment: [This plunk](http://plunker.co/edit/0qToKpyS3vOH3InpqvMn?p=preview) works fine.

Comment: Oops, didn't see the ng-repeat.

Comment: ajay, here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/marcio0/a5KLT/

Comment: Yeah, I think it's a fiddle issue.  [Same code in plunk](http://plunker.co/edit/WhDvZIKEoSCuj7VLcCy1?p=preview) is fine.

Comment: Although, I am curious why it doesn't work in the fiddle... Interesting.

Comment: this plunkr uses ang 1.0.7, i think its related to 1.1+

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of using `style="background-color: {{category.color}};"` try using [ng-style](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angStyle) like this:

```
ng-style="{backgroundColor: category.color}"
```

[Here is an updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5t57n/) that will create the markup you want consistently.

Comment: yes ng-style is better way to go then style attribute in angular

Comment: Or the escaped version `ng-style="{\'background-color\': category.color}"`

Answer (score 1):

This looks like [a bug in the Angular 1.1x-branch](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/2754). The only work-around I can come up with is to remove the style in your template and manually setup a watch in your link-function:

```
template: '<span class="category-label" ng-bind="category.name"></span>',
link: function (scope, element) {
    scope.$watch('category.color', function() {
        element.attr('style', 'background-color: ' + scope.category.color + ';');
   });
```

**Update**

Using ng-style is of course a much better idea.

Comment: Nice catch.  [Here's the updated plunk](http://plunker.co/edit/94qcX7GNJoheX9XWuqZS) that reflects the $watch.